# When I sort my filtered search results my gridview displays all instead sorted

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a gridview and when I search for a specific string I sort my filtered results but instead the gridview shows all sorted and i lose my filtered results. any ideas?

ASP:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridViewWinners" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="PlayerID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" ForeColor="#333333" 
            GridLines="Horizontal" Width="858px" 
            onselectedindexchanged="GridViewWinners_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            AllowSorting="True" Visible="False">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PlayerID" HeaderText="PlayerID" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="PlayerID" Visible="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" 
                    SortExpression="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" 
                    SortExpression="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="Login" 
                    SortExpression="UserName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ClubNumber" HeaderText="Club Number" 
                    SortExpression="ClubNumber" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DOB" HeaderText="DOB" SortExpression="DOB" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GameCenterPrizesConnectionString1 %>" 
                DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Players] WHERE [PlayerID] = @PlayerID" 
                InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Players] ([UserName], [ClubNumber], [FirstName], [LastName], [DOB]) VALUES (@UserName, @ClubNumber, @FirstName, @LastName, @DOB)" 
                ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GameCenterPrizesConnectionString1.ProviderName %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [PlayerID], [UserName], [ClubNumber], [FirstName], [LastName], [DOB] FROM [Players]" 
                UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Players] SET [UserName] = @UserName, [ClubNumber] = @ClubNumber, [FirstName] = @FirstName, [LastName] = @LastName, [DOB] = @DOB WHERE [PlayerID] = @PlayerID">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="PlayerID" Type="Int64" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ClubNumber" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DOB" Type="DateTime" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ClubNumber" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DOB" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PlayerID" Type="Int64" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Before sort:
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=j82tcx&s=6

after sort:
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=rvcz07&s=6

Comment: Can you please give more details? Post code samples, give specifics. It's almost impossible to help otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gridview control does not actually do the sorting, it uses the datasource control to sort the data. The gridview control passes the sorting expression to the datasource control, and the datasource control will sort based on the expression, if it is capable of doing so.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwf94875.aspx

Hope this helps.
--Doc

Comment: it helps but it still does not tell me why the gridview is losing my search results after I sort and displaying everything instead. Any ideas?